# Azure dedicated SQL Pool doesn't allow using identity column as distributed column and is limited to INT ,BIGINT.Please help me understand

Tags: azure

Azure dedicated SQL Pool doesn't allow using identity column as distributed column and is limited to INT ,BIGINT.Please help me understand this limitation.

Azure dedicated SQL Pool doesn't allow using identity column as distributed column and is limited to INT ,BIGINT.Please help me understand this limitation

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: provide the code and also refer to the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-identity#skewed-data

Answer (score 0):

In dedicated SQL pool uses **IDENTITY** property to create **surrogate** keys on tables.

A surrogate key on a table is a column with a unique identifier for each row.You can use the **IDENTITY** property to achieve this effectively without affecting load performance.

***Note:In Azure Synapse Analytics, the IDENTITY value increases on its own in each distribution and does not overlap with IDENTITY values in other distributions. The IDENTITY value in Synapse is not guaranteed to be unique if the user explicitly inserts a duplicate value with “SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON” or reseeds IDENTITY. For details, see*** [CREATE TABLE (Transact-SQL) IDENTITY (Property)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=azure-sqldw-latest&preserve-view=true).

The **IDENTITY** property is designed to scale out across all the distributions in the dedicated SQL pool

create the table having the IDENTITY property using the below syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T1
(    C1 INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
,    C2 BIGINT NULL
)
WITH
(   DISTRIBUTION = HASH(C2)
,   CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
)
;
```

**Populate the table:**

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.T1;
```

[image]

In the above example, two rows landed in distribution 1.
The first row has the surrogate value of 1 in column C1, and the second row has the surrogate value of 61.
Both of these values were generated by the **IDENTITY** property.

Regarding the datatypes limited to INT ,BIGINT.
If all the data ends up in a single distribution, then effectively the table has access to only one-sixtieth of the values of the data type.
For this reason, the IDENTITY property is limited to INT and BIGINT data types only.

Know more about the [Skewed data](https://i.imgur.com/do1SClt.png)